# Duration to TemporalUnits

Tags: java-time

How do I convert a duration to a set of temporal units? I have a duration, and I want to divide that into for instance whole years, whole days and fractional seconds.

I have found [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) for JodaTime, but it seems to facilitate printing as well as division into units, i would just like the division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you speak about the new `java.time`-package of Java-8 or about Joda-Time so I try to present solutions for both libraries.

Most important aspect however is that you cannot divide a `Duration` defined in seconds into years, months etc. in a self-consistent manner because month-based units vary in length of seconds and days. At least not possible without any trick.

Best you can do in this case is to use a reference timestamp in order to recalculate the duration you have. That means you **add your duration to the reference timestamp and then evaluate the new duration between the old reference timestamp and the result in years, months, days etc.** This is also called **normalization** and has nothing to do with printing/formatting.

### Java-8:

```
Duration dur = Duration.ofSeconds(5000001); // example
LocalDateTime ref = LocalDateTime.now(); // reference timestamp
LocalDateTime end = ref.plus(dur);

System.out.println(ref);
System.out.println(end);

// normalize first the calendrical part
LocalDateTime ldt = ref;
long years = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(ldt, end);

// find the months part
ldt = ldt.plus(years, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(ldt, end);

// find the days part
ldt = ldt.plus(months, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ldt, end);

// find the hours part
ldt = ldt.plus(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(ldt, end);

// find the minutes part
ldt = ldt.plus(hours, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(ldt, end);

// find the seconds part
ldt = ldt.plus(minutes, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(ldt, end);

// print the new normalized duration in ISO-8601-format
System.out.println(
  String.format("P%1$dY%2$dM%3$dDT%4$dH%5$dM%6$dS", years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds));

// example output
// 2015-03-17T12:54:07.943
// 2015-05-14T09:47:28.943
// P0Y1M26DT20H53M21S
```

Compared with old JDK pre 8 this can be considered as much better because at least elementary methods for calculation of a duration in one given unit are offered. But a general duration type for handling all units spanning from years to seconds is completely missing. And the best duration formatter I could find is just `java.util.Formatter`.

### Joda-Time

That is the second-best Java library when duration handling is needed, in most details better than Java-8 on this area. Joda-Time indeed offers a duration type spanning from years to seconds (and millis) called `Period`. See here the much simpler solution:

```
Duration dur = new Duration(5000001 * 1000L); // in milliseconds
LocalDateTime ref = new LocalDateTime(); // reference timestamp
LocalDateTime end = ref.plus(dur);

// construct normalized duration
PeriodType type = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime().withMillisRemoved();
Period p = new Period(ref, end, type);

// print the new normalized duration
System.out.println(p); // P1M26DT20H53M21S
```

Small note: I have left out fractional seconds (in Joda-Time limited to milliseconds, in Java-8 up to nanoseconds) in given examples. It is easy to enhance the examples if you really have need for this precision.

Comment: Thank you. Anchoring to a specific time was the key insight. I was meddling with the estimated durations of ChronoTypes, but that turned out messier than this code. I suppose that both variants could be interesting: duration in generalized units (estimated time) and accurate units (which requires a time anchor).

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Happy it was useful. For information, my library Time4J realizes this anchor concept via this ultra-short way: `net.time4j.Duration.of(5000001, SECONDS).with(SystemClock.inLocalView().now());`, the new duration is then automatically normalized.